# Is every 1x1 matrix a diagonal matrix?

Tags: matrices

By definition of a diagonal matrix, a square matrix is said to be diagonal if all its non-diagonal elements are zero. 
So, can a 1x1 matrix be considered diagonal by this definition?

Comment: Yes: $1 \times 1$ matrices are diagonal, even according to this definition.

Comment: @Crostul even though it does not have any diagonal elements?

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'if all non-diagonal elements are zero'? In this case it is a diagonal matrix, since there are no non-diagonal elements.

Comment: In this case, "all non-diagonal elements are zero" is vacuously true, because there is no non-zero non-diagonal element.

Comment: And by extension, a 1x1 matrix with element zero is a non-diagonal matrix?

Comment: @Zwolf: nope. In the definition, the diagonal elements play no role, so any $1\times1$ matrix is diagonal because all its *non-diagonal elements* are zero.

Comment: @Zwolf there is a trivial isomorphism between scalars and 1x1 matrices that preserves addition and multiplication, so in a way yes. But as objects they are different, but they behave the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is $n \times n$, it's a diagonal matrix iff for all $1 \le i \neq j \le n: A_{i,j} = 0$, all its *off-diagonal* entries are $0$.

A $1 \times 1$ matrix has none, so the demand is voidly/trivially fulfilled. In other words: there can be no counterexample, so it's true.

Answer (score 1):

> By definition of a diagonal matrix, a square matrix is said to be diagonal if all its diagonal elements are zero.

Actually, a square matrix is diagonal if all its **non**diagonal elements are zero.

---

And yes, under this definition, becaues a $1\times 1$ matrix has no nondiagonal elements, it is by definition diagonal. The claim

> "every nondiagonal element of a $1\times 1$ matrix has property $X$"

is true for all properties you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, every $1 \times 1$ matrix is diagonal. The only entry is along the diagonal, so the matrix consists of real numbers along the diagonal (which is $1$ spot) and $0$s everywhere else (which is nowhere).